# How to group records, by a relation name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, chartkick

I'm using **Rails 4.2**, [Chartkick](http://chartkick.com/) & [GroupDate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) gems, To display statistics about purchased orders.

**order.rb**

```
  class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :ice_creams
    ...
  end
```

**ice_cream.rb**

```
  class IceCream < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_and_belongs_to_many :flavors
    has_many :added_extras
    has_many :extras, :through => :added_extras
    belongs_to :order
    ...
  end
```

**extra.rb**

```
  class Extra < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :added_extras
    has_many :extras, :through => :added_extras
    ...
  end
```

My intention was to display a chart showing the following:

Count of overall purchased **Orders or Ice Creames** grouped by **Extra's Name**.

In another expression, The last chart is intended to display the most popular **Extras** customers consume.

**graphs.html.erb**

```
<%= line_chart IceCreams.all.joins(:added_extras).group(:extra_id).count  %>
```

The chart actually works but I cant' get it to display the **Extra** name, Or even group by **Extra** name.

[image: Chart indexes **Extras** by its ID]

Anyway my question is...

- How to be able to display the **Extra** name instead of id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join Extra table through AddedExtra table. Try below:

```
IceCreams.joins(added_extras: :extra).group('extras.name').count
```

Comment: Thank dude, you saved me. Can you provide a reference or a documentation ?

Comment: You can find in this Rails Guide page at Chapter 12 Joining Tables. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html